# Program that writes to /dev/stdout: how to send EOF?

Tags: c++, file, unix, stdout

I have a program that writes data to a file. Normally, the file is on disk, but I am experimenting with writing to `/dev/stdout`. Currently, when I do this, the program will not exit until I press Ctrl-C . Is there a way for the program to signal that the output is done ?

Edit:

Currently, a disk file is opened via  `fopen(FILE_NAME)`, so I am now trying to pass in `/dev/stdout` as `FILE_NAME`.

Edit 2:

command line is

`MY_PROGRAM -i foo -o /dev/stdout > dump.png`

Edit 3:

It looks like the problem here is that `stdout` is already open, and I am opening it a second time.

Comment: A program written in which language?

Comment: Also -- saying `/dev/stdout` implies that you're opening a separate handle, rather than using the pre-opened FD 1. If you're doing something like that, an answer will need to know the details to be full and complete -- this is a place where a [mcve] would b helpful.

Comment: (Effectively, `open("/dev/stdout")` is equivalent to `dup(1)` -- it just makes another copy of a file descriptor you *already have*, because you inherited it from your parent. Absent a compelling reason, that's not *generally* a thing one should do).

Comment: Err -- now you're saying C++, but tagging C. These are two very, *very* different languages. Could you correct either the tag or the text such that they're consistent?

Comment: Sorry, is a mixture of c and c++ - file io is handled using older fopen/fclose interface.

Comment: I think I see the problem. `stdout` is already open, and I am opening it a second time. So, perhaps I need to close it a second time for the program to exit.

Comment: Right -- you need to close both the original copy inherited from your parent process on FD 1, and also the copy you opened separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EOF condition on a FIFO (which, if you're piping from your program into something else, is what your stdout *is*) is set when no file handles are still open for write.

In C, the standard-library is `fclose(stdout)`, whereas the syscall interface is `close(1)` -- if you're using `fopen()`, you'll want to pair it with `fclose()`.

---

If you're also doing a separate `outFile = fopen("/dev/stdout", "w")` or similar, then you'll need to close that copy as well: `fclose(outFile)` as well as `fclose(stdout)`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean `fclose(1)` ?

Comment: No, I mean `close(1)`. `close` takes a file descriptor, which is a number (0 for stdin, 1 for stdout, 2 for stderr, higher values dynamically assigned for other handles); `fclose()` is a higher-level call taking a handle. If you were going to use `fclose`, you'd need `fclose(stdout)`.

Comment: Thanks! So, I am calling `fclose(/dev/stdout)` but I still need to type Ctrl-C in console for program to exit.

Comment: @Jacko No you aren't, you are calling `fclose(stdout)`.